# Selenium webdriver C# hyperlink selection with css selector

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
    <div id="welcome-menu" class="panelContainer" style="display: block;">                

<ul>
<li>
        <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" id="aboutDisplayLink">About</a>

        <div class="modal hide" id="displayAbout">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
                <h3>About</h3>
            </div>
            <form name="frmSelectEmployees" id="frmSelectEmployees" method="post" action="/index.php/communication/beaconAboutAjax" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="companyInfo">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <p>Company Name: OrangeHRM (Pvt) Ltd</p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p>Version: Orangehrm OS 3.3.1</p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p>Active Employees: 9</p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p>Employees Terminated: 0</p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>


        </div></form>


     </div></li>
    <!--                        <li><a href=""></a></li> -->
                            <li><a href="/index.php/auth/logout">Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Any one knows how to select element with :

```
<li> <a href="/index.php/auth/logout">Logout</a> </li>.
```

I have tried following option :

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "a[href*='/index.php/auth/logout']")]
```

Also tried link text and tag name. nothing is working. Anyone can help please? thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to identify the element you can use either of the following line of code :

- *linkText* :

  ```
  [FindsBy(How = How.LinkText, Using = "Logout")]
  ```
- *CssSelector* :

  ```
  [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "li > a[href='/index.php/auth/logout']")]
  ```

Comment: thanks, I have already tried these options but its not working. Error is  "Message: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : Could not find element by: By.LinkText: logout"  .  Also tried CssSelector.

Comment: `its not working` doesn't throws any light on what wrong happening. Update the question with the relevant _HTML_ , your code trials and the error stack trace.

Comment: See there is no issue with the `LinkText` or the `CssSelector`. As the element is within the _Modal Dialog Box_ (`div class="modal-body"`) you have to induce [`WebDriverWait`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) with proper [`ExpectedConditions`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)